# AngularJS what does locals in directive stand for

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

AFAIK this is not documented, but I found in angular source a `locals` attribute in a directive example:

```
angular.module('transclude', [])
          .directive('pane', function(){
             return {
               restrict: 'E',
               transclude: true,
               scope: 'isolate',
               locals: { title:'bind' },
               template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
                           '<div style="background-color: gray">{{title}}</div>' +
                           '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                         '</div>'
             };
         });
```

What does it do? How can I use it?

### EDIT

to be more precise:

**How can I access `locals` from `directive`'s controller or `link`ing function?**

**How can I dynamicly change `locals` from `directive`'s controller or `link`ing function?**

**Can I use `locals` in every directive, or does it have to be a directive with a `transclude=true` ?**

Comment: Can you point to the location where you saw this?

Comment: it is present in the http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js file search for 'transclude'

Comment: read the angular source file it says **@param {Object=} locals Optional object. If preset then any argument names are read from this object first, before the `$injector` is consulted**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to close this question.
So the answer is like @ArunPJohny said

**@param {Object=} `locals` (Optional object).**

**If preset then any argument names are read from this object first, before the `$injector` is consulted**

Answer (score 1):

The example code is on the [ngTransclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angTransclude) page, inside the `script.js` tab.

I believe this is just the older syntax (which still seems to work).  The newer syntax would replace

```
scope: 'isolate',
locals: { title:'bind' },
```

with

```
scope: { title: '@' },
```