# What does the "locals" argument to $controller do?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular, `$controller` takes two arguments - `constructor` and `locals`.

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller)

The documentation basically just says that:

1. `locals` is an object.
2. "Injection locals for Controller."

But I still don't understand what it does. Can anyone elaborate and explain?

Comment: I believe it's an obsolete alternative to "scope": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192974/angularjs-what-does-locals-in-directive-stand-for

Comment: Can you give an example of where you would use `$controller` to begin with? I've never used `$controller` as an injected service before, but `locals` sounds like it would be a list of the things you want injected to the constructor (i.e. `["$scope", "$location"]`)

Comment: TBH the only circumstances under which I can imagine myself needing to use $controller directly is if Google accidentally hired me to work on angular core...    peeking at the angular source it appears that I was completely wrong earlier, locals contains $scope, it's not an alternative to it.  Lucky escape for Google in not hiring me, then

Comment: Why I'm using it - https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/app/templates/client/app/main/main.controller.spec(js).js#L20

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Locals" allows you to define injectables into the controller - i.e. it defines the objects that `$injector` can locate just for that controller (as opposed to app-wide injectables that could be defined with `.factory`, for example).

The best illustration is with an example:

```
var controller = $controller("Controller1", {
   foo: {
     v: "I am foo"
   }
});
```

Then, your actual controller can inject `foo`:

```
.controller("Controller1", ["$scope", "foo", function($scope, foo){
   $scope.fooVal = foo.v;
}]);
```

It's a very rare case (except in unit testing) that you would need to use `$controller` directly in your code - here's one odd [example where you can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28868373/968155). This is used, however, by `ui-router` and `ng-route` to define controllers for a state/route with ["resolved" values](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve).

Comment: One possible valid use case - when you wish to separate your logic into two separate controller but want to share same scope/vm. For e.g to manage a view having complex filter model and result list. See http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/03/25/AngularJS-A-better-way-to-implement-a-base-controller.aspx